# Correct way to style elements in the View (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, styles

For the view elements, lets say for example we have:

1. A title field
2. A body field
3. A date field

If I create a default view using ASP.NET razor, it will make:

The title field too thin
The body field the same, way too thin and short.
The date field will not have any special datepicker or such (which is now available in HTML5)

I have my own implementation already, but I would like to know what is the "correct" way to do these kinds of things since they are all related to "stying the front end".

Two main options I see are:

1) Use CSS as much as possible, inserting individual "name=" on the fields.
2) Use Razors EditTemplate/ViewTemplate functionality (I did this for the date)

Another is something about displayextensions, but I haven't read into them too much yet - this is getting confusing.
For the CSS option, I am not sure if I should refer to names I write into the view, or if I can reference the specific options myself without having to edit the view itself too much (by inputting extra classes/names)

Please can you share your answers to this problem, so I can see a common solution.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question. I understand basic ways to style pages. I would like to know how specific I should with my CSS in ASPMVC. Should I be generally targeting the field by its name [name="body"] or by its class .largeTextArea?
There is the [UIHint] Attribute for use in View-Models which are supposed to assist with styling. But I don't see it's purpose beyond rewriting sections of the page. So in that case, why not just use CSS for everything?
My questions loop around which is why I need some clarification from people who have done this a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Jquery, bootstrap and CSS** to make your view look pretty and more usable. For the Date Field I normally use Jquery Date Picker. Depending on the complexity of your ViewModel, view may not generate everything automatically.